# Spring Data JPA @Query doesn't find mapped class

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA and trying to run query like this:

```
@Query(value="select i.content from Item i where i.itemOrder = :order")
List<String> findContentByItemOrder(@Param("order")Integer itemOrder);
```

but it throws exception: 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: **Item is not mapped [select i.content from Item i where i.itemOrder = :order]**

so when I run this:

```
@Query(value="select i.content from package.name.Item i where i.itemOrder = :order")
List<String> findContentByItemOrder(@Param("order")Integer itemOrder);
```

everything works like expected. My configuration:

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("package.name");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setJpaProperties(createProperties());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory.getObject();
}

private Properties createProperties(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");

    return properties; 
}
```

I am using: Spring Data Jpa 1.3.1.RELEASE, Hiberante 4.2, Spring 3.2.1

The problem is that I don't want to put **package.name** for every class name in my Query.How to set Spring Data JPA for finding mapped class automatically ?